# How to select font awesome icon from options

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option> <i class="fa fa-wifi"></i> </option>
    <option> <i class="fa fa-battery-full"></i> </option>
</select>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

When any one of the option is selected, how can I show the selected font awesome icon in feedback div using jQuery.

Comment: You are most likely going to have issues because icons are not valid children for options.  If you put that markup in a page and inspect the options, in the inspector they are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/r62p5zas/
example code is here
In html part u need to integrate and change font of select with font awesome then u chan show icons in select item

```
select{
        font-family: fontAwesome
    }
```

After that u can give onchange event to your select and give value as font name and u need to write code of fonts in options.

```
<select id="dropdown" onchange="chantestge()">

    <option value='fa-wifi'>&#xf1eb; Wifi</option>
     <option value='fa-battery-full'>&#xf240; Battery</option>
</select>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

then is js part u can use jquery and with html code put your result with create icon

```
function chantestge(){

  $("#feedback").html("<i class='fa "+$("#dropdown").val()+"'></i>");
}
```

Comment: From where did you get the value &#xf1eb . I didn't got that on font awesome website

Comment: font awesome site u can reach https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet just add &#x as prefix to code